# Download data from web page in an automated way

Tags: linux, shell

I used to download data from websites and sometimes it is boring and repetitive, So I am wondering is there any way that I can **download data in an automated way**.

For example, I used to download from this link: **“http://isc-mirror.iris.washington.edu/iscbulletin/search/arrivals/#phases”** . and all I need to do and change is filling and selecting a few parameters and click **“search arrivals”**. For example, In my case, I need to click **“Reviewed ISC Bulletin”**, write a phase name (eg, Sg) in **“Phase name:”** part, choose **“Rectangular search”** for both **“Select region for EVENTS:”** and **“Select STATIONS:”**. For example, I want to put *‘50’* for **“Top latitude (-90 to 90):”**, *‘40’* for **“Bottom latitude (-90 to 90):”**, *‘70’* for **“Left longitude (-180 to 180):”**, and *‘80’* for **“Right longitude (-180 to 180):”** in both **“Select region for EVENTS:”** and **“Select STATIONS:”**. I need to change the **“Start date:”** to *“1/1/1964”* and also put a *“date”* for **“End date:”**, and then click **“search arrivals”**, Finally, I will get my outputs. I am thinking to do this in a systematic way and like a loop, getting results year by year, and then output all of them into one file. For each year, the only parameters to change are the **“Start date:”**  and **“End date:”**, while other selections and parameters are the same.

For clarifying more, I provide an example with values, 1) For the first step, I fill parameters as stated above, and put *“1/1/1964”* as **“Start date:”** and *“1/1/1965”*  as **“End date:”**, click **“search arrivals”**, output the results in a file. 2) Then refresh the website, filling the blanks exactly like before and get the output for the next year. We just need to replace the previous **“End date:”**, *“1/1/1965”*, as the new **“Start date:”**  and put *“1/1/1966”* as the new **“End date:”** and click **“search arrivals”** and output it to the previous file(output). I want to continue this process until *1/12/2017*.

The reason for doing this is that If I want to download for a big year range, the size of the output becomes so large, causing the process crash.

I am **using the Linux server and shell and familiar with AWK**. I used to use **Google Chrome** as my internet browser. I have not done such a thing before I am not familiar with such a process for doing so, If somebody can help me how I can get my data in such an automated way, I deeply appreciate.

Best Regards,

Comment: You could use curl or wget to download the text, then awk to pick out the data that you need

Comment: I looked at the page and a `<form>` is used to specify the search parameters.  You are lucky because the `<form>` uses GET to send the search parameters.  So build the searches you want, and submit on the web page.  The URL in the address bar, with all parameters, is what you would request via wget to download the results of the same search later on.  Careful with the recursive options of wget, to make sure you do not follow links.  Then write a script or awk to extract the data as you require.

Comment: @Nic3500 Thank you, I have not used curl or wget yet. Could you please explain how can I Build my searches with them?

Comment: I prefer wget.  You give it the complete URL to connect to and it downloads the entire page, with CSS, JS, ...  It copies the web page to your disk.  There are some recursivity options that will follow links in the page and download those as well.  This can be dangerous, like the time I tried to download the entire Internet overnight (I was recursively downloading an IBM page...  with links to other companies, which contained other compagnies, and on and on.  It stopped when my disk was full!).

Comment: wget info is plentiful, some research will help you.